# JsonMappingException on android spring httprequest

Tags: java, android, json, spring

I have this call in async task. All parameters are correct. In postman or advance rest client the call work fine and It return a json with a list of objects. But if I try to do this call in android with spring I have this error:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
>    at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@1961b5e; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
>    at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@1961b5e; line: 1, column: 1]

This is the expected json response

```
[
{
    "id": 57,
    "user_id": 2,
    "category_id": 5,
    "notification_title": "test 9",
    "notification_body": "breve 9",
    "description": "Sd sdfds sdfs dfsd fdsf",
    "image": null,
    "code": "2-5942525969dfa",
    "start_date": null,
    "expiration_date": null,
    "created_at": "2017-06-15 09:24:41",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-15 09:24:41"
},
{
    "id": 56,
    "user_id": 2,
    "category_id": 4,
    "notification_title": "test 8",
    "notification_body": "breve desc 8",
    "description": "Sdfsdf sdfds dsfs dsfds",
    "image": null,
    "code": "2-59424e24570a2",
    "start_date": null,
    "expiration_date": null,
    "created_at": "2017-06-15 09:06:44",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-15 09:06:44"
}]
```

this is my AsyncTask

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            JSONObject body = new JSONObject();

            try {
                body.put("api_token", Config.API_TOKEN);
                body.put("user_id", Config.USER_ID);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                return template.postForObject(
                        Config.SERVICE_URL_BASE + "/getallposts",
                        body.toString(),
                        String.class
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                listener.onError(e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    List<JSONObject> jsonObjects = ResponseConverter.toJSONArray(response);
                    listener.onSuccess(jsonObjects);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    listener.onError(context.getResources().getString(R.string.cannot_load_posts));
                }
            } else {
                listener.onError(context.getResources().getString(R.string.cannot_load_posts));
            }
        }

    }.execute();
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the spring framework rest tempolate version was wrong, I used the 1.0.1 RELEASE but the correct versione is:

```
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
```